# If wrapper element is -4000 px left alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Having an absolute nightmare and feel like smashing my computer up!

Im trying to see if my .wrapper div is minus X pixels left off screen.

If it is I want to run one function, if not, do nothing. Ive the following so far but it doesnt work at all.

```
  var width = $(window).width();

  setInterval(function(){

  if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('left')) <= parseInt(width*2)){
        alert ('f**k');
    } else {
        alert ('off');
    }

  },1000);
```

Comment: can u not use position().left and check that?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me, looks like you forgot to wrap it in a document.ready: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UX3Rp/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var width = $(window).width();

  setInterval(function(){
  if (parseInt($('.wrapper').css('left')) <= parseInt(width*2)){
        alert ('f**k');
    } else {
        alert ('off');
    }

  },1000); 
});​
```